# WicketTester how to unit test AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior onUpdate?

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to unit test a AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior onUpdate event.  So far I have this:

```
AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior updatingBehavior = (AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior)
                WicketTesterHelper.findBehavior(tester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage("test:form:upc"), AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.class);

tester.executeBehavior(updatingBehavior);
```

However, this does not execute "onUpdate" which I have overridden.  Ultimately, within the behavior I am enabling a component on my page, and I want to assert that this component is enabled after the behavior is executed.  How do I ensure that "onUpdate" is fired in my unit test?

Comment: Does this help? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4670

Comment: Testing Ajax with WicketTester is very hard (at least up to Wicket 1.5, I don't know about later versions). In most cases it is easier (and sufficient) to test the routines inside the behavior and leave the testing of wicket functionality to the wicket developers.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I do something similar and that works just like it should. I can debug it and get to an overridden `onUpdate`. I did not know about the WicketTesterHelper, but it looks useful too :)

```
for ( Behavior b : component.getBehaviors() )
{
    if ( b instanceof AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior )
    {
        this.getWicketTester().executeBehavior( (AbstractAjaxBehavior) b );
    }
}
```

Comment: Even rewrote my code to use WicketTesterHelper. btw. I use wicket 6.10